# NullPointerException when trying to load CSV into Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I dump a Hive table as follows

`hive -e 'select * from sometable' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > /tmp/us.csv`

I drop a destination table and create it again based on a model table.

`drop table blargh; create table blargh like modeltable;`

modeltable is partitioned on a field called mkt_cd so now blargh is too.

I run a script against /tmp/us.csv and modify the timestamp field, adjusting it to be now() in the format YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS  and I write out a file new.csv.    The old CSV /tmp/us.csv had a timestamp in this format which was old and we needed to refresh it.

Finally I try to load with the new CSV file:

`hive> load data inpath '/path/to/new/new.csv' into table blargh partition(mkt_cd);` 
  `FAILED: NullPointerException null`

This error occurs even if I take the "head" (a few rows) of new.csv as my input.   In the editor, it looks good and there are no empty lines.  In addition, this error also occurs if I simply use the original CSV /tmp/us.csv file before I changed it.  What could be a reason here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: No, that has to do with Java programming and in this case I am running some HiveQL in a JVM.  The low-level Java error was certainly unexpected for me so at a higher level I am wondering what in a "load table from CSV" can cause it.

Comment: couple of things i can think of 1. since none row is getting loaded, is modeltable and sometable are of same structure, data type? 2. The timestamp should bein this format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. pls not month is uppercase MM. 3. do you have permission to load into the DB? 4. you havent shared load into script so i am not sure if that has an y issue  5. you havent shared create table so not sure if that has an issue.